# Unable to extract value from a disabled field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, automation

I am trying to automate a process which will extract value of a disabled text field. This will have different data every time we try to access each different record. When i am testing it in Chrome's console as below, i get the desired result. But when i am trying to automate it using win automation, it returns undefined

I have tried the below code.

```js
a = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[15].getElementsByTagName("option")
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].text;
}
```

This exact same line of code does not return any value in the winautomation tool. Please help me with this.

Comment: `a` is `undefined` or what?

Comment: You talk about text field but in the example there is a select with the related options. Furthermore the yours is not the correct way to access the options. You have to use the options property of the select element and use a for...of.      If you provide a minimum complete example I could go throught

Comment: text field had select element and option attribute. i am trying to get the test of options.

Comment: Maybe just try to wrap your code with `DOMContentLoaded`, due to elements aren't ready yet. Take a look https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/oNxWpVW